# Convert the equation into rectangular form

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The polar equation is 
$$r=2\sin(\theta)$$
so knowing what $r$ equals I can use that as one of the "$r$'s" in the equation $r^2=x^2+y^2$
$$2rsin(\theta)=x^2+y^2$$
$$2y=x^2+y^2$$
$$0=x^2+y^2-2y$$
This is where I am stuck because the final answer should be  $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and I am both exhausted and dehydrated and can't figure it out.

Comment: Just add one to both sides of your equations and factor the $y$ part.

Comment: Add $1$ to both sides & complete the square for $y$. ... Drink some water & have a nap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note,
$$x^2+y^2-2y=x^2+(y^2-2y+1)-1=x^2+(y-1)^2-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct, just add and subtract 1 to make it a perfect square.

$x^2 + y^2 - 2y =0 \implies x^2 + y^2 - 2y +1 = 1 \implies x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ , which is same as the answer provided.